# Apple AppStore Legacy App Download Option means no need to maintain code to work for previous iOS version?

Tags: app-store, ios7, version

My app is working perfectly on iOS6. I'm in the work to update my app UI to iOS7. The translucency a flat design is really growing on me. I feel the skeuomorphism design is outdated now.

Do I have to keep checking the device iOS version to maintain the code to work on iOS6 (for eg: set barTintColor on navigation bar will break on iOS6) now that Apple has legacy app download option? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your Deployment Target to 7.0, users with older versions of iOS will not be able to install your new version, so you would not need to take steps to support older versions of the OS.

You set the deployment target in the General tab of your project's settings:

[image: Screenshot of the Deployment Info section of the General tab of project settings]

Users of prior versions of iOS would still have the opportunity to install the previous version of your app.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to keep checking the device's iOS version?

If your new version's minimum deployment target is iOS 7, then no.  If it's iOS 6 then yes.

The legacy app download option will only be available if your new version doesn't support those versions of iOS.